# FragmentBreadCrumbs style - text color?

Tags: android, breadcrumbs

The default text color for FragmentBreadCrumbs is gray. I would like to change it.

From google:

> The default style for this view is Widget_FragmentBreadCrumbs.

I have tried:

```
<style name="CustomFragmentBreadCrumbs" parent="@android:style/Widget.FragmentBreadCrumbs"> <item name="android:padding">4dp</item> <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> </style>
```

And applied the theme to the breadcrumb but the color did not change. What could be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the code of FragmentBreadCrumbs.java, text color is defined by FragmentBreadCrumbs_itemColor.

```
public FragmentBreadCrumbs(
        Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentBreadCrumbs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    mGravity = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentBreadCrumbs_gravity,
            DEFAULT_GRAVITY);
    mLayoutResId = a.getResourceId(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentBreadCrumbs_itemLayout,
            com.android.internal.R.layout.fragment_bread_crumb_item);
    mTextColor = a.getColor(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentBreadCrumbs_itemColor,
            0);

    a.recycle();
}
```